# Are there any monsters or races that can cast spells without verbal components

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, races, spell-components

So a while back I saw the [piper race](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/3rd-party-races/rogue-genius-games/piper/) in their list of racial traits they have the following

> **Mystic Voice (Su):**  Piper spellcasters have a natural magic in their
> voice and must use it as an element of all their spellcasting. The
> additional magic imbued in their voice means a spellcasting piper
> never has to worry about somatic components, and ignores the somatic
> component of any spell. However, pipers cannot cast spells without
> singing out verbal components. Even spells that normally do not have
> verbal components gain them when cast by a piper, and pipers cannot
> use the Silent Spell feat. Further, a piper cannot cast such spells
> quietly. It is not possible for a piper to make a Stealth check when
> casting.

I was wondering if there was a race or monster that can do that but with verbal components. We have the obvious [silent spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/silent-spell-metamagic) metamagic but I'm looking for something innate. My DM approves 3PP as well as Paizo products. Homebrew is on a case by case basis, and I don't want to bother him over something that won't come up right away since I don't plan to use this character immediately unless I really have to. I can use characters that are half-monster allowing them to access 1 or 2 of their monster parent's abilities as long as I'm not doing something like claiming they inherited the power of Cthulhu or something. Let's say CR 4 max to give a hard limit, probably a bit low but better safe than sorry.

So my question is are there any monsters (max CR 4) or races (including 3pp) that can cast spells without verbal components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Astomoi

[Astomoi](https://aonprd.com/RacesDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Astomoi) have the following ability:

> Telepathic Senses: Astomoi can’t speak or see, but can mentally sense the area within 60 feet, as per darkvision, and can speak telepathically. An astomoi can’t see anything beyond 60 feet. *An astomoi must provide thought components for spells that normally require verbal components.* It can use language-dependent abilities with its telepathy, but not abilities that depend on audible components.

This allows them to trade out verbal components for [thought components](https://aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Components&Category=Psychic%20Magic).